# Keras - Theano: ValueError: Input dimension mis-match

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, theano, keras-layer

I have the issue that when running the keras code below I get this error: `ValueError: Input dimension mis-match.` (detailed error message and full traceback below)
This happens only when using Theano backend, for TensorFlow backend everything works fine.
First of all the input:

```
>>> X_train.shape
(37606, 16)
```

The target values `y_train` are stored just in a list as 1 and 0 like this:

```
[0,1,1,1,0,0, ... ,1,0,1,1]
```

The word embedding model has 300 dim:

```
>>> w.shape
(702904, 300)
```

I've read about similar issues where the advice was using two output units (isn't this only necessary for categorical_crossentropy?). I tried this, also with reshaping the target values to: `(37606, 2)`.

But this doesn't solve the problem.
My guess there is some problem with the embedding layer, as the input was specified as `max_review_length = 16` and the embedding provides another 300 dims. But if so, I don't know what to change.

As said above this code works fine using TensorFlow backend.

(Theano is version 1.0.0 and Keras version 2.1.1 on Python 3.4.5)

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas!

```
def create_model(X, Y, summary=False):

    batch_size = 512
    epochs = 5
    sequence_input = Input(shape=(max_review_length,), dtype='int32')
    embedding_layer = Embedding(w.shape[0],w.shape[1],
                            weights=[w],
                            input_length=max_review_length,
                            trainable=False)
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

    attention_probs = Dense(300, activation='softmax', name='attention_vec')(embedded_sequences)
    attention_mul = multiply([embedded_sequences, attention_probs], name='attention')

    x = Conv1D(256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(attention_mul)
    x = Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(4)(x)

    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)

    attention_probs = Dense(32, activation='softmax', name='attention2_vec')(x)
    attention_mul = multiply([x, attention_probs], name='attention2')
    preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(attention_mul)

    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

    if summary: print(model.summary())
    model.fit(X, Y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    return model
seed = 42
np.random.seed(seed)
rn.seed(seed)

model = create_model(X_train, y_train, summary=True)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
evaluate(predictions, y_test)
```

full error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/python_env/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    902             outputs =\
--> 903                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    904                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)

ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 16, input[1].shape[1] = 300)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-456c0ca552d0> in <module>()
     51 #K.set_session(sess)
     52 
---> 53 model = create_model(X_train, y_train, summary=True)
     54 predictions = model.predict(X_test)
     55 evaluate(predictions, y_test)

<ipython-input-15-456c0ca552d0> in create_model(X, Y, summary)
     39 
     40     if summary: print(model.summary())
---> 41     model.fit(X, Y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
     42     return model
     43 seed = 42

~/python_env/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/Keras-2.1.1-py3.4.egg/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1655                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1656                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1657                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1658 
   1659     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

~/python_env/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/Keras-2.1.1-py3.4.egg/keras/engine/training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
   1211                     batch_logs['size'] = len(batch_ids)
   1212                     callbacks.on_batch_begin(batch_index, batch_logs)
-> 1213                     outs = f(ins_batch)
   1214                     if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1215                         outs = [outs]

~/python_env/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/Keras-2.1.1-py3.4.egg/keras/backend/theano_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   1222     def __call__(self, inputs):
   1223         assert isinstance(inputs, (list, tuple))
-> 1224         return self.function(*inputs)
   1225 
   1226 

~/python_env/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    915                     node=self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
    916                     thunk=thunk,
--> 917                     storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
    918             else:
    919                 # old-style linkers raise their own exceptions

~/python_env/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py in raise_with_op(node, thunk, exc_info, storage_map)
    323         # extra long error message in that case.
    324         pass
--> 325     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
    326 
    327 

~/python_env/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    690                 value = tp()
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    693             raise value
    694         finally:

~/python_env/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    901         try:
    902             outputs =\
--> 903                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    904                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)
    905         except Exception:

ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 16, input[1].shape[1] = 300)
Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)](Reshape{3}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0,x}.0)
Toposort index: 105
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, (True, False, True))]
Inputs shapes: [(512, 16, 300), (1, 300, 1)]
Inputs strides: [(19200, 1200, 4), (1200, 4, 4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Reduce{maximum}{2}(Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)].0), Elemwise{Composite{exp((i0 - i1))}}(Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)].0, InplaceDimShuffle{0,1,x}.0), Elemwise{Composite{(i0 + (i1 * EQ(i2, i3) * i4))}}[(0, 0)](Elemwise{Composite{(((i0 / i1) + i2) * i3)}}[(0, 0)].0, TensorConstant{(1, 1, 1) of -1.0}, InplaceDimShuffle{0,1,x}.0, Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)].0, InplaceDimShuffle{0,1,x}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of inverting the two first arguments in the embedding layer? Or maybe transposing the weights before adding them to the Embedidng?

Comment: First, thanks for your answer: I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, did you mean this? changing it to **weights=[w.T]** or **w.shape[0],w.shape[1]** to **w.shape[1],w.shape[0]**  got me different other errors. but even if not I think with transposing the embedding matrix it would also be problematic passing in the input as it need to be multiplied with the input vectors.